# compass and qibla direction app is not working

Tags: android, android-activity, directions, compass

I want to make a compass app which show the Directions along with the direction of Qibla(MAKKAH). I have installed many compass apps but no app is working on my device. I have Samsung Glaxy Core2. Please give me any solution or idea to develop such app and test on my device.
Can my device support this App???

Answer (score 0):

You can list your device's supported Sensors:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager; ... 
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

List<Sensor> deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

So that this will give you idea about what type of sensors are supported and then which one would be enough to make a compass.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html